# Osx terminal: how to open one or more folders/files whose filepaths are the output of a command

Tags: macos, bash, shell, unix, gnu-coreutils

EDIT: I found a solution for this that worked. It's apparently important to quote the file paths to make sure they are read as a whole.

```
path_to_open=$(gfind ~/x/y/ | gshuf | ghead -n 1) && open "${path_to_open}"
```

I've written a command I want to use in osx's terminal. It gets a list of file and folder paths in a directory, shuffles them, and then gets the path that is in the first line of the txt after the shuffle.

This is what I've got so far: [1]

```
gfind ~/x/y/ | gshuf | ghead -n 1
```

With `gfind ~/x/y/ | gshuf | ghead -n 1 > ~/Desktop/z.txt` I get a file path in this format `/Users/me/x/y/some folder/some file.txt` Instead of writing the path of this file or folder to a .txt I want to open it as if I just double clicked on it in finder. How can I do that? I thought the open command[2] was the right one based on the description in the man page, but I'm not sure exactly how to use it. How should I use it? Or, if it's the wrong command, which command should I use?

[1]

I'm using gnu coreutils via macports which is why there's a g in front of the familiar command names

[2]

`open [-e] [-t] [-f] [-W] [-R] [-n] [-g] [-h] [-b <bundle identifier>] [-a <application>] [filenames] [--args arguments]
Help: Open opens files from a shell.
      By default, opens each file using the default application for that file.

      If the file is in the form of a URL, the file will be opened as a URL.
Options: 
      -a                Opens with the specified application.
      -b                Opens with the specified application bundle identifier.
      -e                Opens with TextEdit.
      -t                Opens with default text editor.
      -f                Reads input from standard input and opens with TextEdit.
      -F  --fresh       Launches the app fresh, that is, without restoring windows. Saved persistent state is lost, excluding Untitled documents.
      -R, --reveal      Selects in the Finder instead of opening.
      -W, --wait-apps   Blocks until the used applications are closed (even if they were already running).
          --args        All remaining arguments are passed in argv to the application's main() function instead of opened.
      -n, --new         Open a new instance of the application even if one is already running.
      -j, --hide        Launches the app hidden.
      -g, --background  Does not bring the application to the foreground.
      -h, --header      Searches header file locations for headers matching the given filenames, and opens them.`

Answer (score 0):

To have the folder returned in the results opened in Finder, this should work:

```
open -a Finder `gfind ~/x/y/ | gshuf | ghead -n 1`
```

Comment: Hm. This only opens finder in the foremost/"last active" window when I try it.

Comment: I think the problem is that most of the files have spaces. Could you show me how to pass the result of the command quoted?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

path_to_open=$(gfind ~/x/y/ | gshuf | ghead -n 1) && open "${path_to_open}"